Hair geo nodes dissapear after some frames
I have an animation of a person walking and I made the hair with the geometry nodes asset browser.
I am not familiar with geometry nodes and I can not find anywhere something about frames or someone that has the same problem.
Modifier tab with the hair geo nodes.


How the hair disapear around frame 60 and reappear around frame 260.


the way the hair graudally disappear it seems like a location error or may be out of RAM memory? did you try rendering the scene to see if the error stills show up on the final render? or may be render one of the final frames in the sequence and see if the hair shows up.

I have moved the armature around and it still happens when the location changes. I have not rendered the part where the hair disappears so I don't know yet if it is a viewport error but I will! As for the RAM, I am guessing no cause I see it on a separate program that monitors the RAM and the VRAM usage. I believe it has to do something with the nodes tho...

I rendered it and the hair dissapear..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpnN3XNeQ3EIOjoBSYnq1qMA04gv3RrM/view?usp=sharing
This is the link to the Drive with the file
